# An easy to understand Web2Py training guide

Tags: python, web2py

I am seeking an easy to understand, free, user friendly web2py training resource, that takes the time to introduce each concept and how to use each new object in as much English as possible (and in as little technical jargon as possible).

I want a resource that will leave me comfortable and confident to innovate using web2py, and not one that has me copying and pasting codes with minimal explanation. I'm particular about the MVC coding aspect as I've already figured out how to deploy sites made to PythonAnywhere (and all the elementary stuff like downloading, installing, creating projects, basics of the admin panel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you've seen the [Documentation and Resources](http://www.web2py.com/examples/default/documentation) page, which includes a link to the [Online Book](http://web2py.com/book)? There is a whole host of information and examples there that I'm sure will get you started and serve as a good reference guide.

Comment: Thanks Gareth. I was hoping to get something more easy to digest being that I know Python but not the extremely deep Python (e.g. using Python for user interfaces) that I sense is in the resource you refer to. I was hoping to get a resource that slowly and explanatorily introduces these advanced concepts. It looks like I'll have to make do with what's available. Hmm... So writing my Python code for the app I'm building is proving to be less tasky than getting the application prepared for deployment (e.g. database, userinterface...connection and programming via web2py). Hopefully it gets easier

Comment: You are welcome. The problem is that it's a very broad topic. You need HTML and CSS for the front end, a database for the backend, and your web2py framework which strings it all together.

Hopefully the resources I pointed out will get you going in the right direction, but some more specific help may have to be sought out, for example getting a MySQL database up and running for your needs.

Comment: I just want to mention - I think web2py is a wonderful framework. I've already figured out a lot of the semantics and how to work with the admin panel e.g. to modify and deploy applications live. I'm presently writing the HTML and CSS for the views on my site in Geany. After that I'll go back to Codecademy to brush up my advanced Python - especially classes, then I'll return to web2py to see if I can figure out how to do exactly what I need to do for this project (as a starting point). I'll definitely be knocking on your door if I get stuck anywhere Gareth!